# Ubuntu 18.10 (Guest VirtualBox) - black screen after install Guest Additions and reboot

Tags: virtualbox, 18.10

- Ubuntu 18.04 - host
- VirtualBox 5.2.10
- Ubuntu 18.10 - guest

After install Guest Additions and reboot i see flashing boot text and finally black screen.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as unclear, it's perfectly clear.
Had the exact same issue but mine was resolved by actually ENABLING 3D acceleration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, worked around it by disabling 3D acceleration in the VM settings.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.. This also solves the full-screen issue.

Comment: Not a very pretty solution, but it worked. Guess the VM additions don't play nice with some driver somewhere.

Comment: worked for me too!  Thanks, saved me a ton of guesswork.  For me, it was a Windows 10 guest on a Windows 10 host.  Virtualbox 6.1.30

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue, my solution was to increase the Display Memory to 128MB.

Comment: Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu. May I suggest to add some details to your answer on how to increase the display memory size?

Comment: Increase the Display Memory to 128MB (the maximum) did works for me, thanks !

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Increasing the video memory to max (128MB) worked for me, too! Had 3D acceleration already disabled.